# How to determine whether Right Ctrl/Shift/Alt or Left is being clicked in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to use Right or Left Control/Shift/Alt in C#
but When I type

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(or KeyPress)(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.RControlKey) //(or e.KeyCode)
        {
            //Code
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work...same with Shift and Alt

So what is the wrong here?

Comment: Why not use the [KeyEventArgs.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.control(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: The modifier state is not affected by whether you used the left or right key.   They modify the next keystroke the exact same way.  If you want to detect the right control key then you need if (e.KeyCode == Keys.RControlKey)

Comment: It is not working too @HansPassant :/

Answer (score 1):

In the KeyEventArgs there are properties Ctrl, Alt and Shift that shows if these buttons are pressed.
Or you can do check if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.P) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)) {} in your event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this solve your question or not.

```
 private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    switch(e.KeyCode)
    {
    case Keys.LMenu:
    //Your code for Left Alt Key
    break;
    case Keys.LControlKey:
    //Your code for Left Control Key
    break;
    case Keys.LShiftKey:
    //Your code for Left Shift Key
    break;
    case Keys.RControlKey:
    //Your code for Right Control Key
    break;
    case Keys.RMenu:
    //Your code for Right Alt Key
    break;
    case Keys.RShiftKey:
    //You code for Right Shift Key
    break;
    }
}
```

KeyUp Event:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx

Keys:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Amr Are you focusing on the form?
I think you might be focusing on some controls in the form.

Comment: @Amr Please add this KeyUp Event to every possible control if you need.

Comment: I have also tried on a control...but it doesn't work too :/

Comment: (e.Modifiers == Key.ControlKey) works and anything else works except for >R/L for CTRL/ALT/SHIFT<

Comment: @Amr
so Is there any error in my codes?
I am using KeyUp Event instead of KeyDown Event..
Please let me know your case...Thanks : )

Comment: @Amr
You may also set a breakpoint on the line "switch", so that you can know the value of e.KeyCode (The key value you just pressed.)

Comment: I have used Up and Down...no errors... but also nothing happends

Comment: @Amr so it doesnt trigger the KeyUp Event.
Would you mind to add 
Control1.KeyUp += Form1_KeyUp;
Control2.KeyUp += Form1_KeyUp;

Comment: @Amr add KeyUp Event for all the possible controls in your form.

Answer (score 1):

E.g., if you press RControlKey+A, it creates several events.

```
private void watcher_keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("keyDown: " + e.KeyData.ToString());
}

private void watcher_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("keyPress: " + e.KeyChar.ToString());
}

public void watcher_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("keyUp: " + e.KeyData.ToString());
}

keyDown: RControlKey
keyDown: A, Control
keyPress: 
keyUp: A, Control
keyUp: RControlKey, Control
```

From the 1st or the last event you can know which one (left or right) was clicked. This means you may need to cache the key code as there are 2 keyUp/keyDown events.